# "User Profile Service failed the logon" - no access to user accounts

Tags: windows-7, login

I am trying to repair my friends laptop, which is receiving the error

> User Profile Service failed the logon

When she attempts to log in.

I have looked this up, and most fixes require access to the desktop. So far I have only been able to log in successfully using safe mode, but this does not allow me to use Administrator privileges (like create a new account), even though her account is listed as an Administrator.

- I have also run Startup Repair - could not find any issues
- System Restore (restore point was last week) - no change
- Memory diagnostic found nothing
- Ran a `chkdsk` in the command prompt, but it refused to recognize any input

  ```
  chkdsk [drive letter]: /p /r
  Invalid parameter - /p
  ```

As I have stated before, I have been unable to attempt most options to fix this (i.e. the suggested options provided by Microsoft) due to lack of access to the Desktop, and no Administrator privileges, so options involving software installation, or account management are not possible.

Is there any options I might be able to use other than a full restore?

Comment: Hmm. `/p` is not a valid parameter for `chkdsk` (`CHKDSK [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]] [/B]`

Comment: Did you try with just `/r`?

Comment: [You receive a "The User Profile Service failed the logon” error message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215)

Comment: @DavidPostill no, I'll have to try that next time. As for the link, I tried those but I wasn't able to fix the issue with these because of my previously explaibed issues: no other logins and no access to Administrator priviledges

Comment: @Ben you need to add everything you have tried into your question, this saves all of us time chasing our tails.